# Blender 3.2 : How to animate 3 different objects in one animation, please..?

Tags: animation

It's a traffic light, with a blanking screen and 3 lenses, 1 per colour, each emissive.

I can animate 'Location' for each lens, forward and back, to hide them when 'Off', moving forward each lens so that it becomes visible. Blender plays the animations, in sequence, correctly, but each lens has its own 'channel'. I need to have these 3 animations in one 'channel' (for exporting, where anims are declared by key-frame range: 'Red' 1-50, 'Amber 51-100, etc...).

How may I merge my 3, separate, animations into one 'channel'..? Presently, any export only has one, but not all three.

Disclaimer: Whilst not exactly a 'newbie', I'm far from an expert.

Thanks in advance for any tips or tricks; I've searched around, but found nothing I can apply to my case.

Comment: Can your export include animation of a material channel?

Comment: To me, it's not clear what you mean by "channel". It's probably the channels in the action editor/timeline/dope sheet. But then I wonder how you want to merge them. If you have 3 separate objects and keyframe their attributes, which creates at least 3 channels then you cannot merge them.

Comment: 'Channel', in the Blender I'm using, is the series of Key-frame points for each Property being animated. Typically, and in this case, these are x, y and z Locations. I don't know abot Material channels, so I'll pass on that one.
Since asking this question, I've had a colleague modify my animation such that it all exports correctly, with the 3 lenses moving as they should. My issue seems to have been 'over-thinking' my needs, and creating an 'All-Off' animation which made no sense, in retrospect. I think my issue has been solved, but combining animation data is still beyond me. Thanks, all.

Comment: The solution offered was to remove entirely the key-frames I'd set up for 'All-Off', which had all the lenses behind the screen. This is not necessary; to have all off it's enough to simply not move any forward..! The other difference was in the speed; I had made key-frames from 1 to 50 for each lens; 1 to 3 is enough. With the 'All-Of' eliminated, all worked, and with the shortened length between key-frames, it's all so much faster. Sometimes 'simple' is the key; t'was the case here.